# Selenium WebdriverEvent Listener feature - Does Playwright has a similar feature

Tags: playwright, playwright-java

I wanted to handle clickevent, input events etc in Playwright Java. I know Selenium has inbuilt feature WebdriverEventListener interface and as methods like beforeClickOn, afterClickOn etc.

Does Playwright has any similar feature like this. if yes Kindly help me in sharing a sample code

Read in the documentation and understood there are event listeners to handle frame load, dialogs, dom load etc. But I would also require events to handle click action, input values action

Comment: Can you share your use-case?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```java
// Create a new page
Page page = context.newPage();

// Subscribe to 'click' event
page.onPageCallback((e) -> {
    if (e instanceof Page.ClickEvent) {
        Page.ClickEvent clickEvent = (Page.ClickEvent) e;
        System.out.println("Clicked element: " + clickEvent.target);
        // Perform your actions after the click event
    }
});

// Subscribe to 'input' event
page.onPageCallback((e) -> {
    if (e instanceof Page.InputEvent) {
        Page.InputEvent inputEvent = (Page.InputEvent) e;
        System.out.println("Input value: " + inputEvent.text);
        // Perform your actions after the input event
    }
});
```